# Letting users edit config file after deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, app-config

I have a program which I'm going to deploy using the package for deployment built into VS.

Now I have an app.config file which I want the user to be able to modify (even after running the program), but I have no idea where exactly the installer dumps the files, and I'm not expecting the users to root around their filesystem.

What I was thinking is - I ask the user to specify some directory (which needs to happen anyway since its a game) - I check for the config file there, and if its not there, I copy it from the root directory the program can see - then read the one in the 'save' folder.

That said, its sounding like a very ugly and hacky solution - is there a better one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't be encouraging users to modify the app.config. The app.config is copied into the same directory as your app exe and usually contains settings which your app depends on to run correctly e.g. DB connection strings, system defaults etc. Your playing a dangerous game by letting users change settings in there directly.

A safer approach would be to export another XML file into the users documents folder where they can override app settings. Have your app load in the app.config first then override those values with any settings found in the users own config file.

I would also recommend implementing some sort of UI for this, even if its really basic. Your average user isn't going to be comfortable editing XML directly, too much margin for error.

Comment: Agreed - letting the user edit the app.config directly is asking for trouble because it's harder for you to handle any exceptions that could result. If you roll your own serlializable class and manage its storage yourself, it's easier to handle exceptions.

Comment: Interesting, did not consider that. I think I'll roll my own format since I'm not too much of a fan of hand-modifying XML, and I'm not sure just how many parameters I'm going to need (probably tons)

Comment: Nothing against rolling your own format, however, just note that you would also need to roll your own serializer. Where as .NET has great XML support baked in which would make doing something like this trivial.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the application (or user) settings to persist any changes that the user might want to make in the configuration. See the [`ApplicationSettingsBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx) class and [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/8eyb2ct1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
Say your application contains a user setting called `Score`, managed internally by a class called `MyUserSettings`:

```
public class MyUserSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
{
    [UserScopedSetting()]
    [DefaultSettingValue(0)]
    public int Rank
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)this["Score"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["Score"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

You can save the current values, usually when the main form is closing, using the `Save` method:

```
myUserSettings.Save();
```

If you want users to modify some settings directly, you can use a property grid or your own form that binds the instance of `MyUserSettings` class.
If the settings are marked as "User", then the values would be stored in the `user.config` file, in `%InstallRoot%\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings` or `%InstallRoot%\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data` (for roaming profiles).